# I want to create endpoint for listing all the directories and files for a path. I am using hadoop hdfs library, django, python for the backend

Tags: python, django, hadoop, hdfs

i am trying the following code in my views.py file:

```
def list_of_files(request):
    obj = Hdfs()
    hdfs_path = obj.abspath(path)
    hd = obj.listdir_recursive(hdfs_path)
    i=iter(hd)
    print i.next()
    return path
```

and getting following error:

```
[19/Aug/2016 23:50:24 +0000] middleware   INFO     Processing exception: isdir() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given): Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dm10/Desktop/akira/akiradatabench-backend/build/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.6.10-py2.7.egg/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 112, in get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/dm10/Desktop/akira/akiradatabench-backend/build/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.6.10-py2.7.egg/django/db/transaction.py", line 371, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/dm10/Desktop/akira/akiradatabench-backend/apps/finder/src/finder/views.py", line 43, in list_of_files
    print i.next()
  File "/home/dm10/Desktop/akira/akiradatabench-backend/desktop/libs/hadoop/src/hadoop/fs/hadoopfs.py", line 233, in listdir_recursive
    if self.isdir(path):
TypeError: isdir() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

Comment: what's the type of your `Hdfs()` object? Seems that you have to implement `isdir` yourself. Have you done that and if so can you show us the code?

Comment: https://github.com/cloudera/hue/tree/master/desktop/libs/hadoop i am using this package and using it's classes for listing directories and files for path . i am getting a generator object and while iterating over generator object i am getting this error.

Comment: seems to be a bug somewhere. But looking more closely at your function, I really don't see the point of your code. Where is `path` defined? what is it supposed to do? can you post input & expected output?

Comment: from desktop.lib.django_util import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from hadoop.fs.hadoopfs import Hdfs
import datetime
import json
import os

path =' http://172.31.255.164:50070'

def list_of_files(request):
 obj = Hdfs()
 hdfs_path = obj.abspath(path)
 hd = obj.listdir_recursive(hdfs_path)
 i=iter(hd)
 print i
 print i.next()
 return path

Comment: this is my views.py code . i want to list all the files and directories of this path using that package